# Unexpected behavior from getopts

Tags: shell-script, getopts

Considering:

```
#!/bin/sh

while getopts ":h" o; do
  case "$o" in
    h )
    "Usage:
    sh $(basename "$0") -h      Displays help message
    sh $(basename "$0") arg     Outputs ...

     where:
    -h   help option
        arg  argument."
    exit 0
    ;;
    \? )
    echo "Invalid option -$OPTARG" 1>&2
    exit 1
    ;;
    : )
    echo "Invalid option -$OPTARG requires argument" 1>&2
    exit 1
    ;;
  esac
done
```

This invocation returns `not found` why?

```
$ sh getopts.sh -h
getopts.sh: 12: getopts.sh: Usage:
    sh getopts.sh -h        Displays help message
    sh getopts.sh arg   Outputs ...

     where:
    -h   help option
        arg  argument.: not found
```

This is ok:

```
$ sh getopts.sh arg
```

For this one I was expecting 'Invalid option':

```
$ sh getopts.sh
```

This is ok:

```
$ sh getopts.sh -s x
Invalid option -s
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seemed to have missed printing the message but rather passing the whole string as a command to run. Add an `echo` before the string

```
case "$o" in
  h )
  echo "Usage:
  sh $(basename "$0") -h      Displays help message
  sh $(basename "$0") arg     Outputs ...

   where:
  -h   help option
      arg  argument."
  exit 0
  ;;
```

But generally prefer a style of adding a heredoc to printing out the multi-line string as

```
show_help() {
cat <<'EOF'
Usage:
    sh $(basename "$0") -h      Displays help message
    sh $(basename "$0") arg     Outputs ...

     where:
    -h   help option
        arg  argument.
EOF
}
```

and use the function `show_help` for the `-h` flag.

Also for empty argument flags, the first calls to `getopts()` exits the loop, so you cannot have a handle inside the loop. Have a generic check for empty arguments before invoking `getopts()`

```
if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
    printf 'no argument flags provided\n' >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

With your earlier definition of argument flag `:h`, suggests that `-h` does not take any argument. The clause `:)` only applies when you define `-h` to take an argument i.e. when defined as `:h:`. Only then you run it without passing the arguments the code under `:)` gets executed. Putting together the whole script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
    printf 'no argument flags provided\n' >&2
    exit 1
fi

show_help() {
cat <<'EOF'
Usage:
    sh $(basename "$0") -h      Displays help message
    sh $(basename "$0") arg     Outputs ...

     where:
    -h   help option
        arg  argument.
EOF
}

while getopts ":h:" opt; do
  case "$opt" in
    h )
    show_help
    exit 1
    ;;
    \? )
    echo "Invalid option -$OPTARG" 1>&2
    exit 1
    ;;
    : )
    echo "Invalid option -$OPTARG requires argument" 1>&2
    exit 1
    ;;
  esac
done
```

and running it now

```
$ bash script.sh 
no argument flags provided
$ bash script.sh -h
Invalid option -h requires argument
$ bash script.sh -s
Invalid option -s
```

Comment: Oops! Still, the no-arg invocation does not return a message.

Comment: @Erwann: See update

Comment: The problem with the `cat 'EOF'` construct is that everything is printed on one line. Adding `\n` on each line is ignored. I  invoke `bash script.sh` and GNU bash is version 4.4.19.